# Generate excel based on the query from database using vue and laravel maatwebsite package

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Basically I got a query to get all the record based on the date `from` and `to`. I use `maatwebsite` package in laravel. The problem is if I click the generate button it will not generate an excel file. I'm using version 2.x of this package because it is the stable one. Can someone help me with this? I just only want to print the results of the query in the excel format. I won't change the version to 3.x because if I do that, the import functions of the other component won't work for version 3.x . Thanks a lot

My controller, don't mind the `dd` just for test purposes

```
  public function generateReport(Request $request){

        $date = \DB::table('checkers')
        ->where('remarks_id',2)
        ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
        ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
        ->join('subject_codes','subject_codes.id','=','schedules.subject_code_id')
        ->join('remarks','remarks.id','=','checkers.remarks_id')
        ->where('checkers.created_at', '=>', $request->from)
        ->where('checkers.created_at', '=<', $request->to)
        // ->whereBetween('checkers.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
        ->select('teachers.fullname','subject_codes.subject_description','remarks.remarks_desc','checkers.created_at')
        ->get(); 

        dd($request->from);

        return Excel::download('users.xlsx');
    }
```

If i hit the generate button i got error of `Laravel Excel method [download] does not exist`

Another problem for this is even if i `dd` the request, it returns `null` i don't even know what is happening, i got `v-model` in vue to get the request still cant show.

My vue component

```
         <form action="">
                   <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
                        <label>Start Date</label>
                       <date-picker name="from" id="from" v-model="from" :config="options" ></date-picker>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 form-group">
                        <label>End Date</label>
                          <date-picker name="to" id="to" v-model="to" :config="options" ></date-picker>
                    </div>
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                  <a type="button" href="/generate" >
                    <button  class="btn btn-info">
                        Generate Excel
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
```

The script,  in the `routes.php`, the route for generating is `/generate` and it points to the controller method `generateReport`

```
      data(){
            return{
                    from: new Date(),
                    options: {
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    showClear: true,
                    showClose: true,
                    },

                    to: new Date(),
                    options: {
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    showClear: true,
                    showClose: true,
                    } 
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        methods:{
            generate(){
                axios.get('/generate')
                    .then((res)=>{
                        console.log('asd')
                    })
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you include the `Excel` facade itself? `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;`

Comment: yes sir @niklaz

Comment: `Excel::download('users.xlsx')` - download _what_? You did not even specify the actual _data_ anywhere here - is the class supposed to guess that, or how did you imagine this works?

Comment: That package seems to have pretty decent document, at a glance. I’d suggest you go and actually read up on how this stuff works in there - currently, this is not giving the impression that you actually tried that much.

Comment: yes @04FS i tried doing `return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');` but it says that `FormCollection` not found because im using version `2.x` and I cant switch to `3.x` because there are other functions using `2.x` and it will not function properly

Comment: Well then you will probably have to start by creating the actual Excel document itself, because right now, you don’t appear to even have anything that could be downloaded to begin with. https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/export.html, https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/sheets.html, https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/array.html

Comment: yah thanks sir @04FS, i already read and i tried doing `return Excel::create('report.xlsx');` based on the docs. and now i got a new error. it seems i need to convert it `Object of class Maatwebsite\Excel\Writers\LaravelExcelWriter could not be converted to string`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to get inputs from your form by `$from = Input::get('from');`

```
            Excel::create('file_name', function ($excel) {
                            $excel->sheet('Export', function ($sheet) {
                            // fetch your data
$from = Input::get('from');
$to = Input::get('to');
        $date = \DB::table('checkers')
                ->where('remarks_id',2)
                ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
                ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
                ->join('subject_codes','subject_codes.id','=','schedules.subject_code_id')
                ->join('remarks','remarks.id','=','checkers.remarks_id')
                ->where('checkers.created_at', '=>', $from)
                ->where('checkers.created_at', '=<', $to)
                // ->whereBetween('checkers.created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])
                ->select('teachers.fullname','subject_codes.subject_description','remarks.remarks_desc','checkers.created_at')
                ->get(); 
                            foreach($date as $temp) {

                            $sheet->appendRow('test1','test2');
    }
    })->export('xls');
```

Comment: owkay let me try this sir

Comment: i got this error `continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"` sir

Comment: Paste whole function please.

Comment: lets chat here https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/enQtOTAyMjIzODM5NzQ3LTgyY2Q2ODA1ZjRmNTdkZjAwZmMyYjc3NWYzOGRiNWU5NjEwNWYzM2UyZmE0ODk5OTdhY2NkMWZmM2Q2YTBjYjA